# Why does range in python "stop short"?

Tags: python, range

OK, teaching python to the kids.  We just wrote our first little program:

```
b = 0
for a in range (1, 10)
    b = b + 1
    print a, b
```

Stops at 9, 9.  They asked "why is that" and I can't say that I know the answer.

My code *always* involves files, and my "for row in reader" doesn't stop one line short, so I don't actually know.  In mathematical notation, this behavior would be `[1,10)`.  Technically `(1,10)` would be `2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9`, and indeed I want `[1,10]`.

Comment: I dont know for math notation but in programming u start to count by 0

Comment: meda, in programming you start with any number you want.

Comment: Maroun, can you point me to something that explains *why* it does this?

Comment: @ToddCurry: the reason is simple, range goes up to (not including) the number you pass along.

Comment: The reason for this is simple, assuming you want to run through a list/tuple/etc. you could do this: `for i in range(len(array)): print array[i]`

Comment: Why? Because it is like it is. Somebody decided to let range only increment when it is smaller then the upper bound. That's it. It's just a decision of somebody. There is no god-given law behind it. But meda pointed out an important point. In programming languages you really start counting at 0, not 1. Typical. Of course you can do what you want, but this can result in some confusion as you might see. Every array and list will start with index 0. And - maybe - that's the reason why somebody decided to let rang work like that ;)

Comment: Because range is not for *counting* elements, which is what kids do when they are iterating over this range, but for accessing elements in an array. the reason that arrays begin with 0 is basically efficiency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just how python's `range` works. Quote from [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range):

> This is a versatile function to create lists containing arithmetic
>   progressions. It is most often used in for loops. The arguments must
>   be plain integers. If the step argument is omitted, it defaults to 1.
>   If the start argument is omitted, it defaults to 0. The full form
>   returns a list of plain integers [start, start + step, start + 2 *
>   step, ...]. If step is positive, the last element is the largest start
>   + i * step less than stop; if step is negative, the last element is the smallest start + i * step greater than stop. step must not be zero
>   (or else ValueError is raised).

Comment: Helpful, Alecxe -- critical, explanatory portion is this: "If step is positive, the last element is the largest start + i * step less than stop." 

Thus Python does stop short by design.  Wishing they had been a little more math-friendly is sort of like asking that it be a little more like FORTRAN, so I won't go there.

Comment: Yeah, take a look at other answers - there are some good points on why this was done this way.

Answer (score 7):

It's just usually more useful than the alternatives.

- `range(10)` returns exactly 10 items (if you want to repeat something 10 times)
- `range(10)` returns exactly the indices in a list of 10 items
- `range(0, 5) + range(5, 10) == range(0, 10)`, which makes it easier to reason about ranges

Comment: All true, yet not helpful to the question, which is why python ostensibly acts [x,y) when other languages historically have been [x,y].

Comment: @ToddCurry maybe that's part of the reason they are "historically". Ask this question about them, not about python, that does the sensible thing.

Comment: @ToddCurry This is also exactly the same semantics one uses in c++ `for(int j = 0; j < 5; ++j)`.  Your real problem is you count from one;)

Comment: In Python 3, you can't add ranges, but it works if you convert them into lists first: `list(range(0, 5)) + list(range(5, 10)) == list(range(0, 10))`

Answer (score 3):

The point is that `range` is defined as `range(start,stop,step=1)` http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range. The final element is always less than `stop`.

In practical terms, it is defined that way because the indices of a list of len `n` are numbered `0` to `n-1`.

A more theoretically satisfying answer is that it avoids the alternative, which is that the last element in the sequence would be the first integer which is greater than or equal to `stop`, which would frequently be unexpected. It also leads to the nice properties which Pavel Anossov lists, all of which would be compromised by a greater than or equal rule.

A point on style: It is more usual to write `range (1, 10)` without the space, because `range` is a function which returns a list (or in 3.x, a generator) of the items in the requested range. `for` loops in python always iterate sequentially over the elements of a datastructure or generator (in general, an `iterable` object).

Comment: Marcin, appreciate the response.  In most languages I learned in the 80s and 90s, the expected response would be for the last element to be precisely equal to the last integer in the range -- take a look at Pascal and FORTRAN and you'll see.  Your point on the general zero as unary makes sense.  Thanks.

Comment: @ToddCurry Not sure what you mean about "the general zero as unary" :s. As to Pascal, I found it too full of fiddly rules to learn. FORTRAN I have mercifully forgotten. You'll note that the behaviour here approximates that of C-style for loops.

Comment: @ToddCurry Additionally, I believe that each of those languages used 1-based arrays, which made the behaviour you describe desirable for iterating over arrays.

Comment: I think it is not intuitive. I would rather have 'less than or equal to'. When someone tells me 'Count from 1 to 10' I will go 1,2,3....10. When they tell me 'Count from 1 to 10 in steps of 2'  I will go 1,3,5,...9. This makes intuitive sense to me.